# Remote debugging via IntellijIdea

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I want to configure debugging flow for the application that is placed on a dedicated Linux server. I can connect to the server via SSH for now(with private key protection). F.E. `ssh -i private_key.txt user@host`. But I can't create a connection to the server via Intellij Idea to debug remotely(sample on the picture).
Q: do I need to add some properties to the java application. Or I need to build a connection in a different way.

[image: remote debug config]

Comment: How do you start on server-side the application to which you want to connect?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Spring Boot application with embedded tomcat server

Comment: @MatteoNNZ via command `java -jar bla.jar`

Comment: IntelliJ shows you arguments for the JVM (`-agentlib:jdwp`...)... have you added them when starting the program (before you click on connect from IntelliJ)?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ nope, how I can do that? just type something like `java -jar bla.jar -agentlib...` ?

Comment: Yes, simply `java -agentlib:... -jar bla.jar` (put it right after `java`). Once started, you should be able to connect remotely.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ nope :( still have a problem `Unable to open debugger port (host:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection timed out: connect"`

Comment: and I see the message after starting jar `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000` (on the remote server).

Comment: @MatteoNNZ server protected with ssh private key. That's could be as a reason?

Comment: oh, I see that firewall blocking possibility to debug.

Comment: You're not launching the right configuration. Your argument says port 8000, but you try to connect on port 5005.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the JVM on a remote host with the command line IDE shows you. And make sure the `port` and `host` that are specified in this command is accessible from the host where IDE is running.